# How does work Sinon.JS fake.yields?

Tags: node.js, sinon

I just started investigation of Sinon.JS and after some research I stuck with the following two methods and do not know how exactly they are working:

```
sinon.fake.yields(callback[, value1, ..., valueN]);
```

and

```
sinon.fake.yieldsAsync(callback[, value1, ..., valueN]);
```

It would be great if somebody explain (or even show some example) how they work and when should I use them. One more important question what is the difference between fake, stub and mock in common?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

[The Sinon docs](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v6.1.5/fakes/#sinonfakeyieldscallback-value1--valuen) explain that `yields()` returns a `fake` that "expects the last argument to be a callback and will invoke it with the given arguments".

`yieldsAsync()` does the same thing but invokes the callback asynchronously.

Looking at the [Sinon source code](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/blob/master/lib/sinon/fake.js#L98-L122) makes it clear exactly what this means:

Calling `sinon.fake.yields(...)` records the arguments passed and returns a function.

When the returned function is invoked it ignores all of its own arguments except the last one which it assumes is a callback.  It then invokes that callback with the arguments it recorded from when it was created with `yields()`:

```js
import * as sinon from 'sinon';

const fake = sinon.fake.yields('arguments', 'passed', 'to', 'yields');
const callback = (...args) => {
  console.log(args);
}

// logs the following to the console:
// [ 'arguments', 'passed', 'to', 'yields' ]
fake('every argument', 'except the last', 'is ignored', callback);
```

`yieldsAsync()` does exactly the same thing except that it [invokes the callback asynchronously](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/blob/722ac09f23fa5b87fa8e71b5feac5341314281a3/lib/sinon/fake.js#L105-L107).

In Sinon, a spy "is a function that records arguments, return value, the value of this and exception thrown (if any) for all its calls".  It just spies on the calls made to it.  It can either wrap nothing or it can wrap and transparently pass through to an existing function.

A stub is a spy "with pre-programmed behavior".  A stub lets you spy on the calls made to it and also lets you define how the function should behave (return value, exception thrown, etc.).  If an existing function is wrapped in a stub the behavior defined by the stub is used instead of the function.

"`fake` was introduced with Sinon with v5. It simplifies and merges concepts from spies and stubs."  It spies on the calls made to it like both spies and stubs, it can be created with or without behavior and it can also wrap an existing function.

A mock is a fake method "with pre-programmed behavior...as well as pre-programmed expectations".  A mock lets you define how the function should behave and also how it is expected to be used.  Calling `verify()` on a mock will fail if the mock was not used as expected.